# How to create a contructor for a static method in PHP class

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, static, method-chaining

I already know how to create a `__construct()` method in a class that is executed first before the function you specify is executed, when you create an instance of that class. My class is static with many methods - all static.

What I would like to achieve is create a method that is always executed whenever a static method is called. The purpose of this is that I would like to create a singleton class by hard injecting the instance of another class into a static property and using the static property to access all its methods.

```
<?php 
class ArrayObject {

  private $input_array;

  private $output_array;

  //this method removes elements with null values
  public function clean(array $array)
  {
    #...code to remove empty value elements

    //set the value of the output to the output array
    $this->output_array  = $result;
  }

  //this method strips whitespace from array element
  public function trim(array $array)
  {
    #...code to remove whitespace

    //set the value of the output to the output array
    $this->output_array  = $result;
  }

  //this method returns the value of the $output_array
  public function getOutput()
  {
    return $this->output_array;
  }

}
```

Above is the object class to be injected into the static class as a dependency. Below is the static class for implementing this ArrayObject

```
<?php 
class ArrayClass {

  private static $arrayObject;

  //this method sets the value of the $arrayObject
  private static function setArrayObject()
  {
    self::$arrayObject = new ArrayObject();

  }

  //this method removes elements with null values
  public static function clean(array $array = null)
  {
    #...call method to remove empty value elements

    self::$arrayObject->clean($array);

    return new static;
  }

  //this method strips whitespace from array elements
  public static function trim(array $array = null)
  {
    #...call method to remove whitespace
    self::$arrayObject->trim($array);

    return new static;
  }

  //this method returns the value of the $output_array
  public static function get()
  {
    return self::$arayObject->getOutput();
  }

}
```

The reason I am doing this is so that I am able to chain methods in this manner `ArrayClass::clean($array)->trim()->get();`.

You might say, but why not do all these in the static class instead of creating a separate object to do this - the reason I have to create two classes is that I would like one class to handle the array operations and the other to get the array parameters in a chained environment so that I clearly separate the logic.

See that every method requires a valid array. What I would like to do with the static class is to check for null value passed in a chained call. If method call is empty, the static class would take the output array from the previous call and send as input_array to the second chained call so that when you want to chain operations, you only pass the parameter to the first method call.

Now, hoping you have understood all that, my question is : How can I set the `public static function setArrayObject()` to always be executed first whenever any method of the array operations is called in any order? - without having to first call this method inside of every one of the static methods? And without the user whole will be using this class having to create an instance manually first before accessing this functionality?

I would like the use of this class to be completely static from the user point of view.

Comment: What do you expect will be returned by `return new static;`?

Comment: `return new static` returns an `instance` of the static class in order to enable static method chaining. But not the same as the instance when we use the `new` keyword. This is the equivalent of `return $this` in an object

Comment: There's no term `static class`. There's `static method`, which is invoked without class instance.

Comment: Did my description above help you understand what I need to get done? Leave the word order in the static terms aside, not as trivial.

Comment: I do not clearly understand what are you trying to achieve but I suppose simple singleton pattern with `getInstance($my_array)` will be enough.

Comment: There is no such thing as a constructor while calling methods static. There is a work-around and it is not pretty. Inside your static class arrayobject file do the following `ArrayObject::setArrayObject();`. A more decend approach would be `ArrayClass::setArrayObject()->clean($array)->trim()->get();`

Comment: I know I need to call `getInstance()` to create the object. I only don't want to call this manually for every method, considering the methods can be called in random order. I am wondering if there could be a static function in php that could emulate the `__construct()` on objects so that I can use that for creating the `instance` automatically whenever any of the static methods is called?

Comment: `ArrayClass::setArrayObject()->clean($array)->trim()->get();` is more verbose than I have it already as `ArrayClass::clean($array)->trim()->get()` Seems like the method I needed a second pair of eyes to help me find does not exists! I'll redo my `setArrayObject()` method inside of every method to cut my story short - only that I will be performing a check on the `self::$arrayObject` property first to see if its value is already set and only create a `new ArrayObject()` if it has not been done already. Thank for your time. By shoudl you find a better magic just post it...

Comment: It is `__callStatic`

Comment: Problem here that you don't clearly understand what is it `static`. Construction `return new static` refers to `late static binding` of php and will return instance of a class, name of the class will be resolved in a runtime, not in a compile time. So, writing `return new static` is useless, all this calls will return new object of class `ArrayClass`.

Comment: @u_mulder `__callStatic` is called whenever you make call to a static method that has not been defined yet. It is not obviously the way to solve the problem we have here coz our method is already clearly defined - all we are wondering is how to call it without having to call it manually...sounds rather abstract...

Comment: @u_mulder The code above works perfectly fine - no need to leapingly attack the code. I am only looking to optimize the code. if you want to chain static methods you must use `return new static;` unless you have never chained static methods before - you can give it a try in your text editor and locahost.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the **[Factory](https://github.com/enumag/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/FactoryMethod)** design pattern? By that you can achieve that you call static method which creates instance of a object and you can avoid using kind of weird structure like this: `ArrayClass::clean($array)->trim()->get();`

Example:

```
<?php

class Array {

    // you can implement all your methods here

    public function getOutput() {
    }

    // ...

}

class ArrayFactory {

    public static function create($params) {
        // you can call all necessary cleaning methods here
        // before creating new object

        return new Array($params);
    }

}

// usage:

/** @var Array **/
$array = ArrayFactory::create($params);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I would not like to implement all methods at once because the user may not always need to call all the methods at once. This is an Array helper class I have developed. You may only need to remove null element by calling `ArrayClass::clean($array)->get()` or you may only need to remove whitespace from string values as `ArrayClass::trim($array)->get()` or you may need to do both as `ArrayClass->clean($array)->trim()->get()` All this is easily achieved individually functionality but we would like to create a chainable method call for all methods to emulate OOP.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I can see the point now. However as hard as I think I still cannot come up with a solution to your problem. Why do you want to create chainable method calls and why do you think that it will emulate OOP? If you just want to create helper class that works with array, feel free to use only static methods that doesnt return any object, just array. How would you rename your classes not to use words `Object`and `Class`?

Comment: ArrayObject is a `SPL` library class for manipulating arrays or objects. Many a times in your application you may want to perform different array operations on the same array so that you find yourself nesting function calls - that part is not cool. ArrayObject class implements `implements IteratorAggregate , ArrayAccess , Serializable , Countable{}` and in and of itself does not allow method chaining neither does it have all  the methods you will need to perform in your array. So you can extend it and add methods. Static methods come into place inorder to help me chain method calls..